# Measure network latency through firewall?

Tags: networking

We are trying to use RDP across a very high-latency VPN.   I'd like to measure the latency at each point in the network, but I'll settle for measuring end-to-end latency if that's the only number I can get.

Unfortunately, our network team blocks ping and pretty much everything else.   The only ports that I know for sure are open are 22 (ssh) and the Remote Desktop port which I believe is 135.

Does anyone know of a tool where I can specify a port to measure latency between two hosts?  I have complete control of the machines on each end, it's only the network in the middle I have no control over.

Comment: You can employ the `tcpping`/`nmap`/`tcptraceroute` and many more.

Comment: 1. RDP is port 3389. 2. Try this for testing latency of "real" traffic - http://www.ixiacom.com/products/display?skey=qcheck

Comment: I downloaded the ixia "qcheck" product and it looks cool, but I couldn't get it to work over anything but its native port, which is blocked by the firewall I have to go through.   And Ixia won't talk to you unless you've bought one of their commercial products - even the user manual is behind a paywall!!   So, no help there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer I was looking for by downloading the PSTools package from Microsoft:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx

The PsPing.exe tool is (I guess) the same as tcping and I was able to run a windows-based SSH server on my box behind the firewall and connect to that over port 22:

```
psping -4 -n 100 -h 192.168.123.123:22
```

This gave me a nice histogram list of just how stinky my VPN connection is:

```
TCP connect statistics for 192.168.123.123:22:
  Sent = 100, Received = 100, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
  Minimum = 108.31ms, Maxiumum = 463.88ms, Average = 126.08ms

Latency Count
108.31  87
127.03  9
145.74  0
164.45  1
183.17  0
201.88  0
220.60  0
239.31  0
258.02  0
276.74  0
295.45  0
314.17  1
332.88  0
351.59  0
370.31  0
389.02  0
407.74  1
426.45  0
445.16  0
463.88  1
```